# How many variable assignments take place when creating a list?

Tags: python, list, big-o, variable-assignment, execution-time

I am trying to calculate the execution time of my code using variable assignment as the unit of computation. What I am struggling to follow is how many variable assignments are involved for various methods.

For example, if part of my code was `list = [first, second, third]`, would this be considered one variable assignment (for the list) or would it be three (one for each item in the list)?

The same goes for other methods such as `list.append()`. Would the code `list1.append([one, two, three])` be considered just one assignment as it is assigning the whole list? Or does it count as three? This one could go even deeper with something like `list1.append([max(list2), min(list2), range(list2)])`.

Can someone please explain how to approach execution time in this sort of context? Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question. Two possible approaches are: measure, and calculate. Measure is generally a lot easier because of the (required) complexity of the CPython implementation. It is perfectly possible that some operations in Python are not linearly-related to the time to assign an integer value to a variable. Or perhaps you mean assignment of the value of one variable to another. Or perhaps something else...

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry, I don't follow your answer entirely, this is all very new to me. I'm reading about estimating complexity so I'm trying to gather the terms of my code in respect to variable assignment, so `list = []` and `num = 5` would both contribute 1 variable assignment to the resulting T(n) equation.

Comment: `I am trying to calculate the execution time of my code using variable assignment as the unit of computation` - why? That's not a unit of computation, for pretty much the reasons you're running into.

Comment: @user2357112 I was under the impression that expressed in Big-O notation, complexity was often calculated by assignment statements? Before I can get my code to that stage, do I not need to collect the number of assignment statements in my code?

Comment: I'm no expert, but if you think you will be able to be definitive at the python level you are being IMO very optimistic. There are a rather a lot of possibilities you will have to firstly understand/analyse, then define and map into how long they take to execute. At least with measuring you might be able to get an idea of the average additional time from executing a particular kind of statement. At a higher level, estimating complexity of an algorithm or an implementation should be easier than predicting actual execution time. Good luck!

Comment: `O(n)` because you need to touch each element in the list. This is why `yield` is better than returning a copy of a list.